# GCP - Identity Aware Proxy - How to Retrieve OAuth 2.0 Credentials?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-iap, identity-aware-proxy

I've created a google app engine project with a service protected by IAP.

I understand how to use the [signed headers](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto) to get the authenticated user's identity. But how would I retrieve their OAuth 2.0 credentials?

Any suggestions of other ways of achieving this (using GCP) would also be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by OAuth 2.0 credentials? There are three tokens that can be created using OAuth and OIDC: access, refresh, and identity. If you are using IAP, you can only fetch the user's identity. https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto

Comment: @JohnHanley Specifically the access/refresh tokens. I want, for example, to be able to access the files in the user's gdrive. Since I currently have the frontend behind the IAP, they would have to login to their google account twice to do so; once to get past the proxy, and again so I can get the access/refresh tokens.

Based off of your comment, it sounds like perhaps IAP isn't for me and I should just implement the authorization flow myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three tokens that can be created using OAuth and OIDC: access, refresh, and identity. If you are using IAP, you can only fetch the user's identity.

[Getting the user's identity](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto)

You cannot access the OAuth Access and Refresh Tokens from IAP. If this is a requirement, turn off IAP and implement the Google OAuth flow in your application.